# How to skip duplicate values in the apache velocity js

Tags: velocity, velocity.js

I want to skip the duplicate values so using below code but it seems not working.

```
    #set($uniqueEntities=[])
#foreach($e in $entities)
#if($foreach.index <=12)
#if($uniqueEntities != ($e.offerId))
#set($uniqueEntities=$e.offerId)
#end
$uniqueEntities,
#set($foreach.index = $foreach.index + 1)
#end
#end
```

Response :
OFF-56938,OFF-44046,OFF-27626,OFF-60503,OFF-49318,OFF-52824,1355738,OFF-13099,OFF-27626,OFF-11757,1355717,OFF-27305,OFF-42752

I do not want OFF-27626 to reappear. How could we fix this please?

Comment: Hi Team, any help on this will be really very helpful

Comment: surely there's some better way to format that code sample? I don't understand what you are asking. Are those lines commented out?

Comment: Hi @Matthias no its not commented out. Its the syntax we follow when we write code in apache velocity js

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276608/how-to-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-using-apache-velocity

Answer (score 0):

Without actually knowing velocity.js, looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276608/how-to-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-using-apache-velocity) I think this might work for you

```
#set($uniqueEntities = [])
#foreach($e in $entities) 
    #if( ! $uniqueEntities.contains( $e.offerId )  )
        #if( $uniqueEntities.add($e.offerId) ) #end 
        ##note the if above is to trap a "true" return - may not be required
        $e.offerId
    #end
#end
```

Comment: hi @Matthias, Thank you for your reply but this is not helping. I didnt get the desired result.

Comment: did you try to tweak it and look at the answer/other answers online? I see for example I forgot the index <= 12 part.

Comment: you might also attract other answers if you indent your code correctly